# Why won't dplyr::summarise work with my custom function?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like use a custom function within dplyr's function `summarise()`, as follows:

```
library(dplyr)

# Define custom function for calculating standard error
se <- function(x) sd(x) / sqrt(length(x))

# Create a dummy data table with two groups
d <- tibble(gp = sample(c("A", "B"), 20, replace = T),
            x = ifelse(gp == "A", rnorm(20), rnorm(20) + 1))

# Summarise data
d %>% 
  group_by(gp) %>%
  summarise(x = mean(x),
            se = se(x))
```

Why do I get NA values in the output rather than the correct values of standard error?

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
     gp          x    se
  <chr>      <dbl> <lgl>
1     A -0.4060173    NA
2     B  0.2999004    NA
```

I'm aware of some possible alternatives. For example, using the base package:

```
tapply(d$x, d$gp, se)
```

But I don't understand why the first version gives the result that it does.

Comment: It's a "natural" consequence of the how dplyr is choosing to evaluate things. Instead of `x = mean(x)` just prior, try `x1 = mean(x)`.

Comment: ...one way to think about it is, when it reaches `se = se(x)`, dplyr has to decide the answer to "what is `x`?" There are a couple of "obvious" answers to that question, but the one it picks is the version you just redefined, which now has length one, so no standard deviation.

Comment: I don't think it's reasonable that the version where you don't use your `se` function works. Because, even then it will understand that `x` is only one value with no std dev. Can you check that again?

Comment: @AntoniosK You're absolutely right, I was careless in putting together my example. In the version that I ran, I omitted the line x = mean(x), which of course is the key line as has been pointed out. I've removed that example from the question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`summarize` evaluates each expression in turn, so when your first line does

```
x = mean(x)
```

The `x` column (within each group) is replaced by a single value, `mean(x)`. Your next line calls `sd` on that constant `x`, and the `sd` of a single value is `NA`.

As @joran says in the comments, if you just choose a different name for your mean column, everything will work.

```
d %>% 
  group_by(gp) %>%
  summarise(avg = mean(x),
            se = se(x))
# # A tibble: 2 × 3
#      gp        avg        se
#   <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1     A -0.2879016 0.2264810
# 2     B  0.8804859 0.2625018
```

---

Note that this sequential evaluation is a well-considered feature of `dplyr`. The practical difference between `dplyr::mutate` and `base::transform` is exactly that.

```
dd = data.frame(x = 1:3)
base::transform(dd, x = 0, y = x * 2)
#   x y
# 1 0 2
# 2 0 4
# 3 0 6

dplyr::mutate(dd, x = 0, y = x * 2)
#   x y
# 1 0 0
# 2 0 0
# 3 0 0
```

This is called out in the [*Introduction to `dplyr`* vignette](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html):

> `dplyr::mutate()` works the same way as `plyr::mutate()` and similarly to `base::transform()`. The key difference between `mutate()` and `transform()` is that mutate allows you to refer to columns that you’ve just created.